# Angular 2 build error: '=' expected in index.d.ts

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 2 and out of seemingly nowhere, I started getting the following build error in my node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:

```
Build: '=' expected
```

Luckily I was able to fix this, but I can't find this question anywhere on Stackoverflow, so I figured I'd post a question and answer it myself for anyone who runs into the same issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The newest version of Jasmine seems to have issues with TypeScript versions below 2.1, and Angular 2 seems to have issues with TypeScript versions 2.1+, so to fix this problem, simply change `"@types/jasmine": "^2.5.36"` to `"@types/jasmine": "2.5.36"` (i.e., remove the caret) in your package.json file. You may need to delete your node_modules folder before running `npm install` and restoring your packages.